# How to return a data from a variable and pass it to html page

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

How do you return a data from a variable and pass it to html page.

Ok I have a problem that i am facing now. I want to return all records from the firebase for the users address that is nearby the current user address. I successfully console.log(AllUserAddress) to return all the user's who's address is nearby the current user address. But now my question is how do I return the records to the request.html page.

I did this way at the if-else statement. But it doesn't work. As you can see I use if-else statement to check if the calculated distance is lesser than the limit. If it is true, then send the query to the request.html page. But I tried the following way, it does not work.

```
 if(dist < limit)
       {
         console.log(dist);
         console.log(AllUserAddress);


    this.getRequest = this.angFire.list('request', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'reqdetail',
        startAt: 'regdetails'
      }
    })


       }
```

My openMapPage()

```
geocoder1.geocode( { 'address': AllUserAddress}, (results, status) => {
    var limit = 10;
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latitude1 = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var longitude1 = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      this.latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);
      //var userAddress = new LatLng(currentUserAddress);
       //console.log(latlng1);
       var dist: number = parseInt((google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(this.latlng,this.latlng1) / 1000).toFixed(2));
       var good = true;



       if(dist < limit)
       {
         console.log(dist);
         console.log(AllUserAddress);


    this.getRequest = this.angFire.list('request', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'reqdetails,
        startAt: 'reqdetails'
      }
    })


       }


    } 
  });
```

My request.html page

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title name="title">Job Requests</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div class="filter">
<button class="islandwide" ion-button large>Islandwide</button>
<button class="nearby" ion-button large (click)="openMapPage()" id="nb">Nearby</button>
 </div>

<ion-list>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let user of getRequest | async" class="job">
     <button ion-item (click)="goToJobDetails(user.$key)" class="info">
    <ion-avatar class="avatar" item-start>
        <img src="../assets/icon/user_male-512.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2 class="name">{{user.regdetails.username}}</h2>
    <p text-wrap class="address"><ion-icon name="compass"></ion-icon> {{user.regdetails.address}}</p>
    <p id="key">{{user.$key}}</p>
     </button> 
  </ion-card>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

My Firebase console.

[image]

So when I click NearBy button. Nothing seems to show.

[image]

Comment: That is not an HTML page. Also, I don't understand your question: if your JS runs on-page, then you already have access to everything you need, can you rephrase and better describe what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi  Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans  check the updated post.

Comment: Hi do you know anyway?

Comment: Your question is still very poorly worded: what does "how do I return the records to the request.html page" when you *already* have JS capable of getting the data you need? Your JS works, just use *more* JS to create the DOM nodes necessary and append them to the relevant part of your page? (optionally with wiping the node you're adding them into first?)

Comment: Look i just want to query the records from the request table whose user is nearby the current user address. How do i approach it? Does it make it clear now?

Comment: Clear? No. Are there places where I can point you to? yes. For one, "var dist: number " is not JavaScript syntax, so I'd be amazed if the parser makes it past that line (pretty sure your console will tell you there's an error on that line), but fixing that (just remove `: number`) networked API requests are *always* asynchronous so you need to look up the API documentation for that `getRequest` function you're using. It's a good bet it either returns a Promise (which you'll need to handle with `.then()`) or requires passing a reference to a callback function.